# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '48.5200.048.5200.0200

Tags: python, valueerror

I am a newbie to programming and I recently came across this error. I am working on the Space Analysis dataset from Kaggle and the Price column is a panda series. I tried using astype() to convert it into float and int which was working fine a while ago but now it shows me the Value error. When the astype() is removed the TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' occurs.

```
    df_money = df_.groupby(["Organisation"])["Price"].sum().reset_index()
    df_money["Price"] = df_money["Price"].astype('float')
    df_money = df_money[df_money["Price"]>0]
    df_money.head()
```

---

Error was:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '48.5200.048.5200.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200
```

Comment: How many decimal points does a number usually have?

Comment: You have described your problem (albeit insufficiently, because there is no [mre]). What is your question? [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what should the result be when converting that string to a number? Why?

Comment: @Sayse and Karl Knechtel ohh I see your point. Thanks !

Comment: @PranavHosangadi My question was how do I get rid of the error? (Also, thanks for the feedback will be cautious with the second one!)

Answer (score 0):

This means some record in your `Price` column likely has a string with the literal value `"48.5200.048.5200.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.0200.0200.037.0200.0200.037.0200"`

This string format cannot be naively converted to a number, and thus the conversion fails.

Later you do a comparison between that column and `> 0`. Python, while dynamic, is still strongly typed, meaning that you can only usually compare values of the same type. A string isn't a number and cannot be compared to a number, hence the TypeError if the `Pricing` column contains strings.

To resolve your issue, you will have to somehow convert your long string to something that *can* be converted to a number. You can typically only convert something with a single decimal separator. For example, `float("48.5200")` will work, but `float("48.5200.048")` won't.

I believe your `groupby.sum()` is probably creating this long string. Convert the `Price` column to a float *before* doing the groupby operation.